# Why does a boolean need to be atomic?

Tags: multithreading, rust

In rust, there is such a thing as an [AtomicBool](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html). It is defined as:

> A boolean type which can be safely shared between threads.

I understand that if you're using a boolean to implement a thread lock, to be used from multiple threads to control access to a resource, doing something like:

```
// Acquire the lock
if thread_lock == false:
    thread_lock = true

...

// Release the lock
thread_lock = false
```

Is definitely not thread safe. Both threads can read the thread_lock variable at the same time, see that it's unlocked (false), set it to true, and both think they have exclusive access to the thread.

With a proper thread lock, you need a boolean where, when you try to set it, one of two things will happen:

- Trying to acquire a lock can fail if another thread already has a lock
- Trying to acquire a lock will block until no other threads have a lock

I don't know if Rust has a concept like this, but I know Python's `threading.Lock` does exactly that.

As far as I can tell, this is NOT the scenario that an `AtomicBool` addresses. An `AtomicBool` has a `load()` method, and a `store()` method. Neither return a `Result<bool>` type (implying the operation can't fail), and as far as I can tell, neither do any kind of blocking.

What exactly does an `AtomicBool` protect us from? Why can we not use a regular bool from different threads (other than the fact that the compiler won't let us)?

The only thing I can think of is that when one thread is writing the bits into memory, another might try to read those bits at the same time. A bool is 8 bits. If 4 of the 8 bits were written when the other thread tries to read the data, the data read will be 4 bits of the old value, and 4 bits of the new value. Is this the problem being addressed? Can this happen? It doesn't seem like even in that scenario, a bool would need to be atomic, since of the 8 bits, only one bit matters, which will either be a 0 or a 1.

Comment: There are `Mutex` and `RwLock` for thread locks.

Comment: You can also use `atomic_bool.compare_and_swap(false, true, SeqCst)`, which will set the boolean to true and return `false` only if it was original false. This can be used to implement a lock, but it is not necessary when you could just use a `Mutex<()>`.

Comment: It is not about a race accessing the bits of the bool, but about other memory accesses. Memory concurrency is complicated, but take a look at https://cfsamsonbooks.gitbook.io/explaining-atomics-in-rust/ for `WTF?/AHA! < 1` introduction.

Comment: Whether or not you can think of some way something can go wrong is irrelevant. Either the applicable rules guarantee it's safe or they don't. Things can fail in ways that nobody can think of and rules and standards exist so that we don't have to try to think of every possible way something can fail.

Comment: *What exactly does an AtomicBool protect us from?* - in short, from compiler and CPU reordering of instructions that optimize single-threaded programs, but break multi-threaded ones. See [this article](https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) for examples of compiler reorderings and [this](https://preshing.com/20121019/this-is-why-they-call-it-a-weakly-ordered-cpu/) and [this](https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/) for CPU-based ones. (Not posting as an answer because of too many external links.)

Comment: Let's put your question another way. Why does a byte need to be a boolean? Why can't we just use `u8` and tell all if blocks to check if `u8 > 0`? In reality, booleans don't exist at assembly level; `bool` is just a Rust concept that guarantees a `u8` must be `0` or `1`, similar to `NonZeroU8` that guarantees a `u8` must be `1` up to `255`. And an `AtomicBool` is simply an `AtomicU8` that guarantees the loaded value to be `false` or `true`. So, what's the point of `bool` when we have `u8`? That's the point of `AtomicBool` when we have `AtomicU8`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'll have to check those out. Thanks. @SOFe you explanation started off making sense, but then trailed off. A bool is just a `u8` with a restriction on its values. Makes sense. What exactly is an atomic bool restricting? It has exactly the same possible values as a bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly does an AtomicBool protect us from? Why can we not use a regular bool from different threads (other than the fact that the compiler won't let us)?

Anything that might go wrong, whether you can think of it or not. I hate to follow this up with something I can think of, because it doesn't matter. The rules say it's not guaranteed to work and that should end it. Thinking you have to think of a way it can fail or it can't fail is just wrong.

But here's one way:

```
 // Release the lock
 thread_lock = false
```

Say this particular CPU doesn't have a particularly good way to set a boolean to false without using a register but does have a good single operation that negates a boolean and tests if it's zero without using a register. On this CPU, in conditions of register pressure, this might get optimized to:

1. Negate thread_lock and test if it's zero.
2. If the copy of thread_lock was false, negate thread_lock again.

What happens if in-betweens steps 1 and 2 another thread observes `thread_lock` to be `true` even though it was `false` going into this operation and will be `false` when it's done?

Comment: At first, when you said `The rules say it's not guaranteed to work`, it wasn't clear WHAT wasn't guaranteed to work. That's literally all I want to know. Your example however demonstrates that when using a bool, reading and writing works fine in a single-threaded application. You can be sure that what you wrote is what you'll read back. On the other hand, in multi-threaded applications, you can't always be sure that what you wrote is what you'll read back unless you use an atomic variable, like AtomicBool. Thanks for the great example.

Comment: @John It could be even worse than that. The memory could be used temporarily for another purpose and you might corrupt arbitrary other bits of data. The rules simply don't say what will happen, so you don't know what will happen.

Comment: So using non-atomic variables from multiple threads is inherently unsafe. Even simple read/write operations are unsafe, and can produce unexpected results. They can only be used safely from a single thread. This has nothing to do with your code, or how you use them, and more to do with how the kernel decides to interact with the memory. Bottom line is, NEVER use regular variables from multiple threads in any language that gives you direct access to them. Higher level languages may make these operations safe by transparently wrapping them in some sort of mutex. That sound right?

Answer (score 2):

The thread lock in Rust is `Mutex`. It is typically used to provide multi-thread mutable access to a value (which is usually the reason why you want to lock between threads), but you can also use it to lock an empty tuple `Mutex<()>` to lock on nothing. I can't think of good reasons that you need to lock threads without needing to lock on particular values, though; for example if you want to write to a log file from multiple threads, you might want to have a `Mutex<fs::File>` like this:

```
let file = Arc::new(Mutex::new(fs::File::create("write.log")?));
for _ in 0..10 {
    let file = Arc::clone(&file);
    thread::spawn(move |file| {
        // do other stuff
        let mut guard = file.lock();
        guard.write_all(b"stuff").unwrap();
        drop(guard);
        // do other stuff
        Ok(())
    })
}
```

For atomic values, usually the most important primitives are not `load` and `store` but `compare_and_exchange`, etc. Atomics can be thought as "lightweight" mutexes that only contain primitive data, but you perform all operations you want in a single call instead of acquiring and releasing it in two separate operations. Furthermore, mutexes can actually be implemented based on an `AtomicBool` if the operating system doesn't support it, like the following code:

```
struct MyMutex(AtomicBool);
impl MyMutex {
    fn try_lock(&self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        let result = self.0.compare_exchange(false, true, Ordering::SeqCst);
        if result {
            Ok(()) // we have acquired the lock
        } else {
            Err(()) // someone else is holding the lock
        }
    }

    fn release(&self) {
        self.0.store(false, Ordering::Release);
    }
}
```

You can share *any* value that is `Sync` from multiple threads, provided that you can deal with the lifetime properly. For example, the following compiles without any unsafe code:

```
fn process(b: &'static bool) {
    if b { do_something () }
    else { do_something_else() }
}

fn main() {
    let boxed = Box::new(true);
    let refed: &'static bool = my_bool.leak();
    for _ in 0..10 {
        thread::spawn(move || process(refed));
    }
}
```

You can also do this with non-`'static` references with the sufficient tools, such as wrapping them in `Arc`s, etc.

> A bool is 8 bits. If 4 of the 8 bits were written when the other thread tries to read the data, the data read will be 4 bits of the old value, and 4 bits of the new value.

This cannot happen in Rust. Rust enforces ownership and borrowing very strictly. You can't even have two mutable references to the same value on the same thread, much less on different threads.

Multiple mutable references to the same value is always Undefined Behaviour in Rust; there are no exceptions to this strict rule. By declaring that a reference is mutable, the compiler is allowed to do various optimizations on your code assuming that we are the *unique* place that can read/write the value; not other threads, not other functions, not even other variables (if `a: &mut bool` and `let b = &mut *a`, you can't use `a` before `b` is dropped). You will have much worse problems than writing different bits concurrently if you have multiple mutable pointers.

(By the way, "writing bits" to the same value is not a correct way of thinking it; it's much more complicated than "writing bits" in modern CPUs even without Rust's borrow checking rules)

TL;DR: If you don't have the `unsafe` keyword anyway in your code, you don't need to worry about race conditions. Rust is a very memory-safe language where memory bugs are mostly checked at compile time.

Comment: I'm not talking about Rust. I'm talking about the concepts. They are language-agnostic. It doesn't matter what the compiler does, or doesn't let you do. I want to know WHY it even has an `AtomicBool`, as opposed to just letting us use bools in multiple threads. With your example, I now understand that an AtomicBool does have some useful methods, like `compare_exchange`, which can not be safely done with a regular bool from multiple threads. Just using `load` and `store` on the other hand sounds no safer than using a simple bool.

Comment: See @DavidSchwartz's answer for that. In general, concurrent writes to the same memory is undefined behaviour, no matter how many bits *seems* to be effective. In fact, there is no `AtomicBool` at the OS/arch level; there is only atomic byte, and strictly speaking, concurrent writes to the same memory, even with the same value, can legally cause any unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @SOFe Saying that "concurrent writes to the same memory is undefined behavior" doesn't help because it doesn't answer _why_ it's undefined behavior. It's not obvious that it must be - for example, in the JVM memory model [it isn't](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262428/race-conditions-in-jvm-languages-versus-c-c/262440#262440).

Comment: And Rust does not have a [defined memory model](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/memory-model.html).